# Rails Daily/Monthly Report

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Report

I need to create a daily report + monthly report with this records.. All records is from one table and under one field('nature' is the name of my field)..

```
Calls
Texts
Emails
```

Is there any possible way to create a single query that will
generate this daily report + monthly report.?

Ex.

```
          Day1    Day2    Day3    etc..    Total
Calls     20      23      23      ...      66

Texts     120     125     130     ...      375

Emails    50      60      55      ...      165

Total     190     208     208     ...      606
```

If not, please tell how to do it the simplest way, and how to this on rails.?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What are the numbers? Number of record created during the month?

Comment: for example.. i have 20 calls on day1, 25 on day2, 25 on day3, etc...

Comment: and you have the models defined? How much do you know about rails for now?

Comment: i'm a newbie on rails..please tell me how to do it the simplest way..thanks

Comment: I've tried this query

SELECT count(id) AS Total,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM docus WHERE doc_categ='query' AND date_rec='20120501') AS QUERY1,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM docus WHERE doc_categ='query' AND date_rec='20120502') AS QUERY2,
-----
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM docus WHERE doc_categ='query' AND date_rec='20120530') AS QUERY30,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM docus WHERE doc_categ='query' AND date_rec='20120531') AS QUERY31
FROM  `docus`
WHERE date_rec
BETWEEN  '20120501' AND  '20120531'
AND `nature` LIKE 'Calls'

and repeats for the Texts and Emails..

Is there any way to make it simple?

Answer (score 0):

for One month

```
$todayDate = date("Y-m-d");
$thismonth = strtotime($todayDate);
 $next_month =  mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+1, date("d"), date("Y"));
```

query

```
select colum_name from table_name where month(table_field_name) BETWEEN month($thismonth) AND month($next_month) AND year(table_field_name) BETWEEN year($thismonth) AND year($next_month)
```